# How to make Regex work to find 7 letter words that start with A

Tags: regex

Working on a Java program that can grab words from a text doc that start with "A" and are 7 letters longer. I am trying to use Regular Expressions in Java.

Might someone give me some pointers here how to do this?

```
`Pattern sevenLetters = Pattern.compile("^\\w{A}{6}$");`
```

Does not obtain what I'm aiming for unfortunately.

What is the syntax that goes into the ()?

Thanks

Comment: To match `A` it should be `^A` not `\\w{A}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe,

```
\\bA[a-z]{6}\\b
```

might simply work OK.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){


        final String regex = "\\bA[a-z]{6}\\b";
        final String string = "Aabcdef Aabcdefg Aabcde Aabcdef \n"
             + "Aabcdef Aabcdefg Aabcde Aabcdef ";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/I5X4sw/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/I5X4sw/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]